# What does 'Roodow (wrongly spelled, only the sound)' mean?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation, australian-english

In Australia, I have met a lot of people saying a word (sound like) 'roudow' to respond (mostly to end, like 'alright' equivalent) a conversation. I have been searching around but haven't got any clue yet due to the spelling. Would you please kindly talk a bit about this for me?

Comment: You might have misheard people saying **righto** http://australiandictionary.net/righto

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply!! Very much appreciated!

Comment: You can hear it as the first word of this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWMbn2jXCGc

Comment: I'm pleased to help. I think part of the reason for mishearing in this case, is because Australian pronunciation often involves pronouncing letter *t* when it is inside a word, like a quiet letter *d*. That's something in common with American and Canadian accents.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mishearing

Comment: Lemme see, that might be something like [rɔytæᵚ] in Broad Strine.

Comment: @Tristanr I suspect you're almost certainly correct. You should post that as an answer so that it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: I forget, are regional slang terms on-topic?

Comment: user867, that might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You might have misheard people saying **righto** http://australiandictionary.net/righto

I think part of the reason for mishearing in this case, is because Australian pronunciation often involves pronouncing letter *t* when it is inside a word, like a quiet letter *d*. That's something in common with American and Canadian accents.

You can learn more from the **Consonants** section of the article at this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_English